# Vsyncing a windowed mode opengl game at 20FPS until a GDI window becomes topmost

Tags: c++, opengl, gdi, ati, vsync

My single threaded Double buffered Opengl game is running across two monitors using one HWND, HDC and HGLRC combination. So each frame buffer is 2560 x 1024 in size.

My PC is:

Intel Core 2 Quad CPU @ 3.00GHz
ATI Radeon HD 3400 Series 512MB VRAM DAC 400MHz
Both monitors are tuned to 60Hz and (1280 x 1024) resolution.

I am seeing my game with vsyncing OFF run at about 36FPS. When vsyncing is turned on the game syncs to 20FPS, until a GDI application like task manager gains focus and renders on top of it. We then see the game framerate rise to 30FPS whilst the task manager has focus. FRAPS confirms my profiled framerate as being accurate.

is 20FPS an expectable vsync rate? As I was under the impression the valid values for 60Hz monitor were 60,30,15,10...?

I also managed to knock up a background texture demo to run with the same initial renderer settings as my game and I am seeing 72FPS with Vsync OFF, whilst Vsync ON syncs to 30FPS. What happened to syncing to 60FPS?

It's almost as though I am missing a vsync interrupt or timer, unless a GDI window is present.

FYI I'm using QueryPerformanceCounter to get the hi-res timer to work out all the FPS calculations.

Comment: How have you setup your open GL context across these monitors? See here: http://www.rchoetzlein.com/theory/2010/multi-monitor-rendering-in-opengl/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have read the link and implemented that renderer which is different to the method I describe in my post. That method works fine for my PC and an S3 440 based machine but some cards do not support Multi-head in that fashion such as the Ati Radeon X1300. This is a blocker for me to using this solution.

Comment: 20Hz suggests you're missing 3/2 of all the V-Sync deadlines for a 60Hz monitor output. Anyway, 20Hz is unacceptable for interactive applications.

Comment: Sorry, missed the very start part of the post: *shoots self*.

Comment: Have you tried triple buffering? http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=928593 and http://www.tweakguides.com/Graphics_10.html

Comment: @datenwolf Yes, I need to complete a frame in 16ms for 60Hz and 33ms for 30Hz. Your right that 20Hz is not acceptable in anybodys language lol. Again why should a GDI window in focus cause both fraps and my profiler to improve fps to 30 from 20. Baffling! Thanks for the links DiscoStu, I'll give them a read now there may be something in this I have missed. afaik In Opengl 2.0 you can't programatically set Triple buffering for Opengl like you can with DirectX, it has to be done through the ATI Catalyst driver. Thanks again.